# Operator norm ||T||

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let$g \in C[-1,1]$ . Consider the operator $T: C[-1,1] \rightarrow R$, defined by

$$T_g(f) = \int_{-1}^1 g(t)f(t)dt\;.$$

with  norm $\|f\|=\max_{\|t\in[-1,1]} |f(t)|$

Find $\|T\|$, given $g(t)=t$ for all $t\in[-1,1]$ and $f(t)=t^\frac{1}{n}$, n is a large odd integer

Definition of the norm of an operator $T$: $$\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tf\|_\;.$$

My problem is, when g(t) and f(t) are unknown, I can find $\|T\|$ like this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77364/norm-of-the-linear-bounded-operator-t-defined-by-tfx-int-0x-gtftd). But since g(t) and f(t) was given, I can't help but feel like there is a trap somewhere. Are there any differences between this problem and the other problem that I should be aware of?

Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Something is wrong. The operator $T$ depends on $g$ (i.e., there is a different operator for each $g$). But $f$ is the "variable", so $\|T\|$ (actually, $\|T_g\|$) does not depend on $f$.

Comment: I've fixed your integral limit.  The trick is to write `\int_{-1}^1` (when we want a more complicated expression to be treated the same as a single character, put it in brackets like `{stuff here}`).

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have mentioned, the $T$ you have is not actually a functional of type $T:C[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, but rather is defined by  $$ T = \int _{-1} ^1 t^{1+1/n} dt $$ (just by plugging in the definitions of $g$ and $f$ into the integral). Note that this means that $T$ is actually just a real number, in fact this integral even has a closed form solution.

So for instance, if your question is from a homework problem in a functional analysis class, you've definitely mistranscribed or misinterpreted what was being asked.